# "Merge" LiveValidation with Jquery on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, livevalidation

This is part of my jquery function that validades a form i have on my website:

```
        /*
    validates errors on all the fieldsets
    records if the Form has errors in $('#formElem').data()
    */
    function validateSteps(){
        var FormErrors = false;
        for(var i = 1; i < fieldsetCount; ++i){
            var error = validateStep(i);
            if(error == -1)
                FormErrors = true;
        }
        $('#formElem').data('errors',FormErrors);   
    }



    /*
    validates one fieldset
    and returns -1 if errors found, or 1 if not
    */
    function validateStep(step){
        if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

        var error = 1;
        var hasError = false;
        $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function(){
            var $this       = $(this);
            var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

            if(valueLength == ''){
                hasError = true;
                $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
            }
            else
                $this.css('background-color','#A8FC9C');    /* Campo preenchido */
        });
        var $link = $('#navigation_form li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
        $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();

        var valclass = 'checked';
        if(hasError){
            error = -1;
            valclass = 'error';
        }
        $('<span class="'+valclass+'"></span>').insertAfter($link);

        return error;
    }

    /*
    if there are errors don't allow the user to submit
    */

    $('#enviar_candidatura').bind('click',function(){
        var preenchimentoForm=true;
        if($('#formElem').data('errors')){
            preenchimentoForm=false;

            dadosFormularios(preenchimentoForm);
            //return false;
        }
        else{
            dadosFormularios(preenchimentoForm);
        }
    });
});
```

However, i'm using too LiveValidation (http://livevalidation.com/) to validade fields client-side. Obiously, if the part validated by jquery is Ok, doesn't matter if there's errors on the LiveValidation part because the form is submitted.
So, what i want is to add an if clause or something like that inside this jquery code to verify if there are LV_invalid_fields. If 'yes' then block form from submitting like it's done with the jquery validation part, but i don't know how to do it neither where is the right place in the code above to put this verification. I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//... live validation codes here

$("#myform").submit( function (event) ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(".LV_invalid").length > 0) {
        //do not submit   
    }
    else {
        //do form submission here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change the binding on the `click` to a binding on the `submit` action on the form.
And your function must return `false` on the submit action to stop the submitting action.

So, change your code like this :

```
$('#formElem').submit( function (event) ) {
    var preenchimentoForm = true;
    if ($('#formElem').data('errors')){
        preenchimentoForm = false;
    }
    return preenchimentoForm;
}
```

You can read some explications about unobtrusive javascript [here](http://blog.socialcast.com/unobtrusive-javascript-2/).

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the LiveValidation library which is not explained in the documentation http://livevalidation.com/documentation

To prevent LiveValidation's submission while still keeping its validation events, you may use the "afterValidation" option.

Example:

```
var prevent = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
};

var yourValidation = new LiveValidation( 
    "inputID", { 
    //Your other options
    afterValidation: prevent
    } 
);
yourValidation.add( Validate.Presence, { your options } );
```